# Troubleshooting linear mixed effects model plot and trendline slopes

Tags: mixed-model, data-visualization, trend, ggplot2

I'm working with multiple years of temperature data from different sites in a watershed. I'm using the 7DADM measurements i.e. one temperature reading for each site per year of monitoring.
This is what my data looks like

```
ggplot(use_sevdadm, aes(x = year, y = maxroll, colour = sitename)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5) +
  theme_classic() +
 theme(legend.position = "none",
        panel.spacing = unit(2, "lines"))
```

[image: scatter plot of 7DADM temperatures for each site every year of monitoring]

I've written a mixed effects model using R to see if there is a trend for each site for the years of data I have (15 years, 2008-2022):

`glmmTMB(data = df, formula = temp ~ year + (1+ year|sitename))->mod1`

*As I understand it, I'm saying for each temperature what is the interaction between the year grouped by each site. And the model that it produces should have a random intercept and random slope for each site.*

This results in:

`summary(mod1)`

```
Formula:          maxroll ~ year + (1 + yr_step | sitename)
Data: df

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   776.8    797.7   -382.4    764.8      232 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups   Name        Variance  Std.Dev.  Corr  
 sitename (Intercept) 4.142e+00 2.0351384       
          year        7.289e-07 0.0008537 -0.97 
 Residual             1.096e+00 1.0468734       
Number of obs: 238, groups:  sitename, 17

Dispersion estimate for gaussian family (sigma^2):  1.1 

Conditional model:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) 16.08723    0.51156  31.447  < 2e-16 ***
year      0.05854    0.01601   3.657 0.000255 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

using `ranef(mod1)` I see:

```
              (Intercept)         year
S1          -2.619128562  1.061847e-03
S2           0.016190616 -6.782850e-06
S3           1.571495483 -6.369153e-04
S4           6.298859587 -2.553502e-03
S5          -1.338048169  5.424395e-04
S6           0.483008860 -1.969374e-04
S7          -2.688549545  1.092067e-03
S8          -0.881644350  3.573641e-04
S9           0.512919081 -2.081534e-04
S10         -0.973586630  3.951104e-04
S11          0.008698755 -3.135866e-06
S12          1.446483921 -5.874260e-04
S13          0.818152768 -3.314534e-04
s14          0.371879453 -1.516007e-04
S15         -2.392803620  9.706963e-04
S16         -0.235775404  9.517781e-05
S17         -0.398206974  1.612278e-04
```

To me this means that the slopes (under year) are different for each site which should be visible when I plot the model with the data however when I do plot the data using `ggplot()` I get this:

```
ggplot(use_sevdadm, aes(x = year, y = maxroll, colour = sitename)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5) +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_line(data = cbind(df, pred = predict(mod1)), aes(y = pred), size = 1) +  # adding predicted line from mixed model 
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        panel.spacing = unit(2, "lines"))
```

[image: ggplot of weekly max temp of each site for all years of monitoring with trend line plotted]

See how the slopes all look the same?
My question is **why are the lines not plotting the random slopes of each site that the model is giving me? Is there a way to figure out the problem or force it to plot the lines with the `ranef()` I have?**
Some thoughts I've had that could be why this is happening: the slopes are so small there's an imperceptible change amongst the lines; I wrote the formula wrong in the model;I should use the `coef()` function instead; I need more data points? I'm using 7 day maximums for each site/ year that I've extrapolated from continuous summer daily maximums so there is more data I can use but it just gets unwieldy quickly.

I'm envisioning something that would look like this figure on the right (B) but with my data:
[image: pulled from https://peerj.com/articles/4794/]

You can find the article this figure came from [here](https://peerj.com/articles/4794/)

Thank you for any and all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there just isn't much variability in the slopes between different sites. You can see this in two ways:

- The random slopes that you see under `year` when you run `ranef(mod1)` are all extremely small. These random effects represent how much (or little, in your case) each site's slope deviates from the global (fixed) slope (0.05854)
- Take the variance of the random intercepts (4.142e+00 = 4.142), the variance of the random slopes (7.289e-07), and the residual variance (1.096e+00 = 1.096). The variance of the random slopes only accounts for $\frac{7.289e-07}{4.142 + 7.289e-07 + 1.096}=1.391561e-07\approx0\%$ of the total variance. Meanwhile, the variance of the random intercepts accounts for $\approx79\%$ of the total variability

Therefore, you should not expect to see different slopes for the different sites. You could opt for a more parsimonious model and drop the random slopes i.e.

```r
glmmTMB(data = df, formula = temp ~ year + (1|sitename))->mod1
```